# Unexpected end of JSON input in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, promise, fetch

I'm getting an

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

error when I press submit.

this is my code:

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
app.models
  .predict(
    Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, 
    this.state.input)
  .then(response => {
    if (response) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.state.user.id
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((count) => {
          this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}));
        })
  }
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
  })
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

}

[My app.js](https://gist.github.com/TOcvfan/aa9fea095c93fa646bc341a345f4b779)

I new to React.js and I want to learn more, but I can't figure out why I get this error, and it goes through because the database gets updated. And when I login again, the page is also updated.

the error I get

```
    Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/cmham/Projekter/facedetector/src/App.js:94
  91 |     body: JSON.stringify({
  92 |       id: this.state.user.id
  93 |   })
> 94 | }).then((response) => response.json())
     | ^  95 |   .then((count) => {
  96 |     this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}));
  97 |   })
View compiled
```

how do I resolve this?

**Edit my server part**

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  db('users').where('id', '=', id)
    .increment('entries', 1)
    .returning('entries')
    .then(entries => {
      res.json(entries[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
})
```

**Edit 2**
Now I receive a 1 from the server but what I need is the updated number from the database.

this is my server now:

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  db('users').where('id', '=', id)
    .increment('entries')
    .returning('entries')
    .then(entries => {
      res.json(entries);

})
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
})
```

and this is my App.js:

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
this.setState({imageUrl: this.state.input})
app.models
  .predict(
    Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, 
    this.state.input)
  .then(response => {
    if (response) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.state.user.id
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((count) => {
           console.log(count)
          this.setState({
            ...this.state.user, entries: count++

          });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('An error occured ', error))
  }
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
  })
.catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

I don't get the number from the database, but I no longer get an error

Comment: Please post the answer of the server. There might be a header missing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn that is an object `{id:this.state.user.id}` .

Comment: are you sure you are actually getting the user data back successfully? console.log your this.state.user.id just before you make your fetch to make sure.

Comment: What exactly is in `entries`? Can you post the json response from the server?

Comment: @gifCo I do get the right info from this.state.user.id

Comment: @chrisg86 entries is number of posts and the server give me no response

Comment: If the server response is empty,`.then()` will execute, but fail on this line `(response) => response.json()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of minor issues here

- In your `this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}))`, I understand what you are trying to do here but not sure this is how you want to do it.
- Also you aren't fully handling your promise properly

*logging the value of `count` would also help though (it's possible you are not getting the value you expect*

```
app.models
  .predict(
    Clarifai.FACE_DETECT_MODEL, 
    this.state.input)
  .then(response => {
    if (response) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
          method: 'put',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.state.user.id
        })
      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((count) => {
          this.setState({
             user: Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}) 
// Notice the difference here 
          });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('An error occured ', error))
  }
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(response))
  })
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Also, not very familiar with knex but you may want to change

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  db('users').where('id', '=', id)
    .increment('entries')
    .returning('entries')
    .then(entries => {
      res.json(entries);

})
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
})
```

to something like:

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;

  db('users').where('id', '=', id)
    .increment('entries', 1)
    .then(()=> 
      db('users').where('id', '=', id).then(user => res.json(user[0].entries))
    )
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
})
```

in your `server.js`

I suspect you may also be able to do something like (I've not used knex before but something like this is doable in SequelizeJS):

```
db('users').where({id}).then(user => 
  user[0].increment('entries', 1).then(() => res.json(user[0].entries))
).catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to get entries'))
```

Comment: What's the error you get @TWOcvfan ? Plus can I see your full backend code as well?

Comment: Updated the answer, take a look @TWOcvfan

Comment: It removed the error, but now the server just sends a 1 back @delis

Comment: So what value do you expect from the server @TWOcvfan

Comment: I expecting the new number of entries so it can be updated on the website @delis

Comment: I see what you did there, but it didn't work. Now I just get a blank result

Comment: @TWOcvfan I've updated the answer: (ignore the last bit unless the other one works)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to parse the req.body before extracting it to const id and using it on your DB query

```
const { id } = JSON.parse(req.body);
```

Comment: I do use it in my db query and parsing it just gave me an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: replace res.json() with res.send(JSON.stringify(entries[0])

Comment: now i get a `PUT http://localhost:3000/image 500 (Internal Server Error)
An error occured  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at App.js:95` @Roy.B

Comment: @TWOcvfan what is the response? Can you console.log response before the response.json()

Comment: @TWOcvfan my guess is that the response from db containing html tags  JSON.parse('<...'). Its trying to parse it because of the header Content-Type:application/json,

Comment: @TWOcvfan console log the response like this console.log(response.text()) and verify that nothing is escaped from string then if all good try this JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)),  good luck

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your server code, it seems that you are trying to return the first element from the result array. Returning this would result in a JSON object being sent back:

```
.then(entries => {
  res.json(entries[0]);
})
```

Your frontend code, though, seems to wait for a count and nothing else:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((count) => { ... })
```

---

I'm not entirely sure if that's what you want to achieve, but **sending the entry count back in a JSON object** should do the trick on the backend side. Also note sending back the error as an object in the `catch` block:

```js
db('users').where('id', '=', id)
  .increment('entries', 1)
  .returning('entries')
  .then(entries => {
    res.json({ count: entries.length });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(400)
       .json({ message: 'unable to get entries' })
  })
```

Frontend code also needs some modifications (see the second `then()` and added `catch` block). I would also encourage using 
[the object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of `Object.assign()` as it's easier to read and grasp:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/image', {
  method: 'put',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    id: this.state.user.id
  })
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(({ count }) => {
  this.setState({
    user: {
      ...this.state.user, 
      entries: count,
  });
})
.catch(({ message })=> {
  alert(message)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: my response from the server is now just `{}` and the page doesn't update @chrisg86

Answer (score 0):

this may happen for your server receiving data name and your client sending name is not same. like (//in server (**req.body.userName**) & //in client (fetch....{body:json.stringfy({**username** : user.username//from your state})}

look at the star marks, this user name are not equal.
hope you could solve your problem.

Comment: Hey there. On Stackoverflow it's disencouraged to answer old posts (this one is from 2019) and has been solved. Answering old posts causes them to get "bumped" and become relevant again, which is not what we want of course.

If you like someone's answer that's much more beneficial.